# Component will not update with new api call

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to create a search function for my website that grabs the name of a musical artist and returns some json data which includes the next event of the artist. I have set a default value ("ariana grande") and see that the function calls are running fine but when I input a search for example Guns N' Roses, I get a json file back and update the state but my components mainly the featured component does not update with the new state.items data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './resources/styles.css';
import {Element} from 'react-scroll';

import Header from './components/header_footer/Header';
import Featured from './components/featured';
import VenueInfo from './components/VenueInfo';
import Highlights from './components/Highlights';
import Pricing from './components/Pricing';
import Location from './components/Location';
import Footer from './components/header_footer/Footer';
import { myConfig } from './config';

const myKey = myConfig.KEY_2;


class App extends Component {

  state = {
    items: [],
    didLoad: false,
    query: "ariana grande",
    names: []
  }

  async grabArtistInfo(artistSearched) {
    const artistSearch = `${artistSearched}`
    const url = `https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/${artistSearch}/calendar.json?apikey=${myKey}`
    const response =  await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    await this.setState({items:data, didLoad:true});
  }


  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getSearchedName(this.state.query)
  }

  async getSearchedName(artist){
    await this.setState({query: artist});
    const  searchUrl = `https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.json?apikey=${myKey}&query=${this.state.query}`
    const response = await fetch(searchUrl);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({names: data})
    this.grabArtistInfo(this.state.names.resultsPage.results.artist[0].id)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.didLoad === true) {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Header searched = {(artist) => this.getSearchedName(artist)} />
          <Element name = 'Featured'>
            <Featured 
              deadline = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].start.datetime}
            />
          </Element>
          <Element name = "Venue_info">
            <VenueInfo/>
          </Element>
          <Element name = "Highlights">
            <Highlights/>
          </Element>
          <Element name = "Pricing">
            <Pricing/>
          </Element>
          <Element name = "Location">
            <Location 
              lng = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].venue.lng} 
              lat = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].venue.lat}
              desc = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].venue.displayName}
              locationDetails = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].location.city}
              />
          </Element>
          <Footer/>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div>Loading ... </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I suggested an edit to your code.

Comment: Dont you have my edit suggestion there?

Comment: sorry  I see the edit suggestions but it still does not update the counter with the new data called from the api

Comment: Where is the counter?

Comment: the counter is in the featured component which i pass a deadline prop too provided by the api which i call using this.state.items

Comment: Can you share the `<Featured />` component code?

Comment: [This is a link to my github repo](https://github.com/jcyuen1995/the_venue/tree/master/src)

Comment: Please accept the new edit I made.

Comment: I don't see any `counter` in the `<Featured />` component.

Comment: the featured component creates a new component in the render called timeUntil that contains the counter

Comment: I dont understan what you are trying to do...

Comment: pass  (this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].start.datetime) from app.js to  featured's index.js which creates a timeuntil function that contains a counter that which will use the datetime data the problem i am having right now is that the featured component will not re-render when the app.js state is changed

Comment: Do you want to fetch automatically?

Comment: i want to keep the fetchs in app.js and re-render when getSearchedName() is called

Comment: Well, that's one of the reactjs benefits, it will rerender the dom that changed

Comment: but thats my problem featured component will not re-render with the new state. the new information is passed down but it does not re-render the counter component

Comment: Then something is happening with the data... Maybe you are not getting anything different..

Comment: i have teseted the responses in a browsers console i am indeed gettign different daata

Comment: then your passing has something wrong... You are not passing the correct variable

Answer (score 0):

Remove the await from here
await this.setState({items:data, didLoad:true});
You need to be using functional set state;
Every time you setState you are dropping every other field/key from state.

Comment: removing await does not update the data still. I tried removing async from the function along with all awaits but this produces an error on render.